# Using Pin 26 for ADC?

Tags: esp32, adc, toit

Using pin 26 for ADC seems to be discouraged in Toit.

From what I can see on https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html pin 26 should have an ADC converter, so what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESP32 is [limited](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html) around ADC2:

> Since the ADC2 module is also used by the Wi-Fi, only one of them could get the preemption when using together, which means the adc2_get_raw() may get blocked until Wi-Fi stops, and vice versa.

Therefore I suggest using ADC1-pins if WiFi is used for connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Since All ADC2 Pins Can't be used while using WIFI, You can use ADC1

```
GPIO32  ADC1_CH04
GPIO33  ADC1_CH05
GPIO34  ADC1_CH06
GPIO35  ADC1_CH07
GPIO36  ADC1_CH0
GPIO39  ADC1_CH03
```

Check this video to learn more about esp32 pins and assigned pirepherals:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LY-1DHTxRAk&t=546s